# Wire nuts vs lever nuts

Tags: electrical, wiring

I'm doing some home repair and discovered lever nuts. They look like a great improvement over wire nuts. Though they cost a bit more, ease of installation, tracking the wires, and less bulkiness make up for it, in my opinion.

However, some people are critical. A friend of mine, who is quite handy, says not to use lever nuts because they don't twist the wire for contact, which can create heat. I'm not sure I believe that.

What are the pros and cons of lever and wire nuts?

Comment: Some months after asking this question, I used lever nuts on a new ceiling light installation. I had to revisit the install because the wire inside some of the nuts were sparking and creating heat and burn marks inside the nut. Long story short, I no longer trust them.

Answer (score 1):

I have never used lever connectors but AFIK the WAGO should work great.

They are only approved for copper conductor (not aluminum). With the special WAGO joint compound they would probably work with aluminum. I think they do not accept wires over #12 so this would limit their use with aluminum.

I have heard that there are counterfeit WAGO lever connectors in the market so be sure to get them from a trustworthy source.

Comment: I have used WAGO's but only for lightly loaded devices and circuits. Keep in mind that the standard WAGO is only rated for 7A. Splices where the circuit is heavily used you should stick with the wirenut. I understand that WAGO has come out with a heavy duty connector which I have never used and do not have any information on. Lets just say use the right material for the right job. Also I have never used them on stranded wire. I just don't have the faith that it would be an electrically and mechanically sound connection.

Comment: "Wago makes the 222-series Lever-Nuts in 3 sizes: 2-conductor, 3-conductor, and 5-conductor. They can handle 28-12 AWG wire, both stranded and solid, and are rated up to 600V (1000V for signs and fixtures) and 20A."  https://toolguyd.com/wago-lever-nuts/